# Creating an app script function that generates a chart object for any google sheet

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function in app scripts that generates a chart whenever I pass in the data labels and data points into the function as so:

```
makePiChart(LabelRange,DataRange)
```

labelRange: January,February,March....
DataRange: 5,4,3,.......

However, when I try clicking on a cell and typing in the function with the range arguments I get an error.

I first was trying to test if I could get the chart output for a single sheet.

This is the code I have for that.

```
function makePiChart() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("#Id for Spreadsheet")
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss)


      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("January"); 
      sheet1.activate()


      var chart = sheet1.newChart()
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
      .addRange(sheet1.getRange("C4:C11"))
      .addRange(sheet1.getRange("H4:H11"))
      .setPosition(5,5,0,0)
      .setOption("Issues","Dynamic Chart")
      .build();


      return sheet1.insertChart(chart);


    }
```

Now this generates the chart for the January sheet as I expect.

However, I want to create a function that generalizes this process. So if I go to some sheet in spreadsheet, say I had a Spreadsheet for the entire year and I go to the January sheet, February Sheet, March Sheet etc. and if I click on a cell and type

```
makePiChart(Rangeforlabels,RangeforData)
```

I'll get a piechart object that is made using only those data ranges.

Basically, I dont want to keep modifying scripts to generate chart objects. I want to be able to type in =makePie(labelRange,DataRange) into any cell and have a chart object appear. Its location does not matter.